# Make field required only for new object

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata

There is form with some fields:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $isNew = !$this->getRequest()->get($this->getIdParameter());

    $formMapper
        ->add('title')
        ->add('file', 'file', array('required' => $isNew))
    ;
}
```

Is there better way to make field required only for new objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Sonata `isNew()` function [found here from the docs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/cookbook/recipe_dynamic_form_modification.html):

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $isNew = $this->getSubject()->isNew();

    $formMapper
        ->add('title')
        ->add('file', 'file', array('required' => $isNew))
    ;
}
```

However there's some issues with `$this->getSubject()` not returning the right things. There is [a pull request open to fix these problems](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/2076#issuecomment-65503564) (I've linked to my comment with instructions on how to use the branch in its current state.)

Answer (score 2):

On our side, we are doing the same way than the original post, but we would be happy to know that there is a cleaner solution :)

Event Subscriber looks too complex for a such small need.

Best regards,
Christophe

Answer (score 2):

Using this:

```
$isNew = $this->getSubject()->isNew();
```

throws an error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "isNew" of class "SomeEntity".
```

So I used this instead:

```
if ($this->getSubject()->getId() === null) {
    $isNew = true;      
} else {
    $isNew = false;
}
```

I hope it helps anyone facing the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to add an Event Subscriber To A Form Class you can view an example here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

thanks ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've seen this sollutuon too. But as Christophe noticed below: it is too complex for this simple task.